# I want to convert dictionary with tuples as keys to specific format and then store it in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a dictionary `dic = {(1,2,3): 3, (2,3,4): 2, (3,4,8): 5}` 
I want it to be saved it in the text file **output.txt** with the specified format

```
1 2 3 (3)
2 3 4 (2)
3 4 8 (5)
```

modify the following code for this task

```
dic = {(1,2,3): 3, (2,3,4): 2, (3,4,8): 5}    
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(dic))
```

Comment: Okay, so what are the differences between what you see in the file, and what you want to see in the file? Does this give you any ideas about what to change next? When you write out your desired output by hand, can you describe in English step-by-step how you are calculating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the dictionary and write content to text file.

**Ex:**

```
dic = {(1,2,3): 3, (2,3,4): 2, (3,4,8): 5}
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for k, v in dic.items():           #Iterate dic
        file.write("{} ({}) \n".format(" ".join(map(str, k)), v))  #write to file.
```

Comment: file.write("{} ({}) \n".format(" ".join(k), v))  #write to file.
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: use `" ".join(map(str, k))`

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {(1,2,3): 3, (2,3,4): 2, (3,4,8): 5}
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for k, v in dic.items():           #Iterate dic
        file.write("{} ({}) \n".format(k, v))  #write to file.
```

Here we just have to pass the key and value to the format function. I dont think any other operations has to be done on this.

str.format() is one of the string formatting methods in Python3, which allows multiple substitutions and value formatting. This method allows to concatenate elements within a string through positional formatting.