# python different number of keys dictionary store to text file in specified format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I've a dictionary with the following format
`frequent_itemset= {'11': 23, '23': 20, ('20', '32'): 10, ('2', '3'): 9, ('1', '2, '3'): 5}` etc.
I want to store it in **output.txt** with the following format.

**Expected result**

```
11 (23)
23 (20)
20 32 (10)
2 3 (9)
1 2 3 (5)
```

**I wrote this:**

```
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
        for k, v in frequent_itemset.items():
        file.write("{} ({}) \n".format(" ".join(map(str, k)), v))
```

**result:**

```
1 1 (23)
1 2 (20)
20 32 (10)
2 3 (9)
1 2 3 (5)
```

Comment: Given what you "wrote" is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58390499/1324033) to your last question, what have you tried to try and change fix yourself? Where does your input come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the map, because a string is considered an iterable as well as a tuple/list.

For example, if you iterate through a list containing `["a", "b", "c"]`, you get `"a", "b", "c"`. However, if you iterate through a string `"abc"`, you ALSO get `"a", "b", "c"`.

Try this instead ...

```
frequent_itemset= {'11': 23, '23': 20, ('20', '32'): 10, ('2', '3'): 9, ('1', '2', '3'): 5}

for k,v in frequent_itemset.items():
    if isinstance(k, (list, tuple)):
        key = ' '.join([x for x in k])
    else:
        key = k
    print("{} ({})".format(key,v))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
frequent_itemset= {'11': 23, '23': 20, ('20', '32'): 10, ('2', '3'): 9, ('1', '2', '3'): 5} 

for k,v in frequent_itemset.items():
    print(*k, '({})'.format(v)) if isinstance(k, tuple) else print(k,'({})'.format(v))
```

output

```
11 (23)
23 (20)
20 32 (10)
2 3 (9)
1 2 3 (5)
```

Comment: Yours is a better answer ;)

Comment: @RightmireM both of us have same way, i just wrote it in one line and you have write in more simple and readable way :), also you have give good explanation

Comment: but I like the approach of @RightmireM. that looks much simpler for noobs like me.

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad  i also like his approach, simple and readable, you are not the only one :p

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop:

`for x,y in frequent_itemset.items():
  print((x if type(x)==str else " ".join(x)) + " (" + str(y) + ")" )`

One liner:

`[print((x if type(x)==str else " ".join(x)) + " (" + str(y) + ")" ) for x,y in frequent_itemset.items()]`

Result

`11 (23)
23 (20)
20 32 (10)
2 3 (9)
1 2 3 (5)`